# Starting an SMS chat from DialogFlow API

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es

I am creating a user signup process, after which I'd like to kick off an SMS chat.  I have the user's phone number, and I have the twilio integration with DialogFlow. However, Dialogflow has never interacted with this user before. I can trigger a custom event, but how do I specify the user's phone number when triggering the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. The thing to do is use Twilio or the SMS service that owns the integrated phone number with whatever message we want to reach out to the user with. Now when the user responds, it starts a conversation with Dialogflow! That's enough for most needs!  Hopefully, this answer will help somebody!